# Attaching a library to the header only as needed

Tags: theming, 8

I'm building a new module. For some reason the jQuery only works when the jQuery library is attached to the header instead of the default footer.  While building the module I was attaching the libraries with the following in the file flot_d8.module

```
function flot_d8_page_attachments(array &$page) {
  $attach_footer = FALSE;
  $attach_header = FALSE;
  if ($attach_footer) {
    $page1['#attached']['library'][] = 'flot_d8/flot';
  }

  if ($attach_header) {
    $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
      // The data.
      [
        // The HTML tag to add, in this case a <script> tag.
        '#tag' => 'script',
        '#attributes' => array(
          'language' => "javascript",
          'type' => "text/javascript",
          'src' => "http://test.mysite.com/core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.js",
        ),
        '#value' => '',
      ],
      // A key, to make it possible to recognize this HTML <HEAD>
      // element when altering.
      'jquery-define'
    ];

    // Attach the flot asset on every page.
    $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
      // The data.
      [
        // The HTML tag to add, in this case a <script> tag.
        '#tag' => 'script',
        '#attributes' => array(
          'language' => "javascript",
          'type' => "text/javascript",
          'src' => "http://test.mysite.com/modules/flot_d8/flot/jquery.flot.js",
        ),
        '#value' => '',
      ],
      // A key, to make it possible to recognize this HTML <HEAD>
      // element when altering.
      'flot-define'
    ];
  }

}
```

Obviously, this misses the whole point of having assets defined in the flot_d8.libraries.yml file. I see the supposed "correct" way of attaching assets is to add them to the template. I used the `attach_library()` twig function and tested it with and without the "defer" attribute in the script. My template file (flot-d8-my-template.html.twig) is this:

```
{{ attach_library('flot_d8/flot')}}
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">//<![CDATA[
(function($) {
  $(window).load(function(){
    $(function () {
      $.plot($("#{{div_id}}"), [ {% for seri in series %} {{seri|json_encode()|raw}},{% endfor %}]);
    });
  })
})(jQuery)//]]>

</script>
<div id="{{div_id}}" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
```

Checking the page source shows that when the library is defined in the twig file, both the jquery and flot libraries are included in the aggregated js at the bottom of the page.  Also, on pages which do not render this module, no jquery or flot code is included in the footer. However, the code only renders correctly when I manually force the inclusion in the header using `hook_page_attachments()`

So I have two questions. 
Can anyone help me understand why footer-included libraries do not function in this case, and if I can change something to make them work?
If there is no way to make footer-included libraries to function, what is the best way to force their inclusion in the header only when needed?

Comment: Do not alter the headers, use dependency in your library instead. So only do this $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'flot_d8/flot';

Comment: That will include the library in the footer, which does not work. It seems like jQuery only works when it is included above any code in a template.html.twig file. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2636206

Comment: You are obviously doing something wrong with either your html template or libraries.

Comment: If it's obvious...let me know. The example at the drupal node is as minimal as they get. That version deals only with core/jquery, so there is no library file, and the template is only 12 lines long.

Comment: Give me your html.html.twig and flot.libraries.yml contents.

Comment: The simplified (no flot, just jquery) code is all here(http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-Beakerboy-2635882/tree/?h=8.x-1.x)